# UK Standard visitor visa received but a few documents submitted are missing. How to get them back?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I have submitted the original offer letter of my employment along with the letters as supporting documents for a UK standard visitor visa from India. I have done it through VFS global. I received the visa but a few documents like the opening page of the offer letter are missing. Kindly help me. Is there any procedure to get them back?

Comment: VFS staff should have told you. No documents are guaranteed to be returned. Should have sent photocopies.

Comment: ohhhh..Thank you for the reply. They did not tell me that. Is there any chance if I contact the VFS or the visa enquiry for UK (https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English) ?

Comment: I think it will be difficult now but doesn’t hurt to try.

Comment: ok let me see then!

Comment: You could also contact your employer and ask for a copy of the employment letter, explaining the original was lost in the visa process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was not the only document missed.

Comment: @C0D3R The same principle applies. For each document, consider what you would do if it were irretrievably lost in some other way. Typically, it will be to apply to the issuing authority for a duplicate.

Comment: @HankyPanky [Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) says that "all documents must be originals and not photocopies."

Answer (score 1):

The UKVI, in its Standard Visitor visa application process, states:

> Any original documents you submit as part of your application will be sent back to you.

However, there are occasions when an original document may not be returned, such as when its validity is challenged.. Otherwise, the problem may lie with VHSGlobal, which manages the visa application centres in India, and through which you submit your application, supporting documents, and biometric data.

In such instances, first recourse would be making direct contact with the Visa Application Centre which handled the application. Rather than local contact information, VHSGlobal India web site links directly to the [UKVI help desk](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english) information, a fee based service:

> By phone
>   Telephone: 00 44 203 481 1736
>   Monday to Friday, 24 hours
>   Calls cost £1.37 per minute on top of your standard network charges.
>
> By email
>   [Email UK Visas and Immigration.](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English) 
>   Emails enquiries cost £5.48. You will not be charged for any follow-up emails about the same enquiry.
>
> You’ll get a reply to your email within 2 days, except on Saturdays, Sundays and [UK public holidays](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide).

[enter link description here](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide)